# Using twig templates to display XML

Tags: php, xml, twig

I'd like to use twig templates to display XML data, and I'm not really sure if I'm going about it the best way.

I'm currently generating an xml DOMDocument in PHP and passing that to the template, but at that point the only thing I can think to do go through each document in a loop recreating the tags within the template.

Is there a better way to go about doing this?

Also, how should I set the content type of the page?

I'm not using any kind of framework.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is reason in using Twig and DOMDocument together. They do basically the same thing. You have two possibilities:

**Just convert DOMDocument to string**

You don't need to do it "manually" in twig. You can just do `echo $domDocument->saveXML();`. There is no reason to use templating engine, since you already have formatted data.

**Don't use DOMDocument and use Twig**

If you find twig more convenient, just pass data to twig and generate XML there. Just pass data to template and generate whole XML in way you usually generate HTML.

[To set content type use `header()` php function.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)